# Issues installing scipy from Anaconda2 Python

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda

I'm trying to install scipy, which comes with the package when I first installed Anaconda2 Python. When I run the setup.py file, I get the following error message...

```
from scipy._lib.six import string_types
ImportError : No module named scipy._lib.six
```

... eventhough there is a file called six.py in the scipy/_lib folder

Has anyone ever faced this issue and how did you resolve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Anaconda installed, SciPy is installed already. Just import it:

```
>>> import scipy
```

Don't do this in the directory where the `setup.py` is located.

With Anaconda use `conda` to install packages:

```
conda install scipy
```

will:

1. Either install SciPy, if it is not installed yet,
2. Or update your package to latest available version,
3. Or tell you `All requested packages already installed.`.

If it installs something there will always be a prompt like:

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:

<list-of-package-names>

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```