# Issue installing scipy: Six module not found

Tags: python, scipy, pip

Question similar to this one [Issues installing scipy from Anaconda2 Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428671/issues-installing-scipy-from-anaconda2-python) but I don't have anaconda so the answer there won't work for me.

I'm trying to install 64 bit Scipy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy but I'm getting this error:

`from scipy._lib.six import string_types
ImportError : No module named scipy._lib.six`

The _lib folder does contain a python file called six, though. And I have the Six package installed elsewhere already?

**EDIT**: I've been told it's probably something to do with the python path. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

it's probably solved for you by now but you also need the file called six.pyc. If it's not there, it's probably in usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy. (or replace python2.7 with whatever version you have). Just copy it to scipy._lib, but make sure you choose the right scipy (there could be a usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy AND a usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy (without the local))